# How to have Dired always list only the files that have extension `.org`, for a particular directory?

Tags: dired

I use `C-x d *.org` to list only files with `.org` extension. Is there a way to make this permanent *for that directory*? I have to do this every time I open that directory, it would be nice to have it permanently.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: add better solution in response to comment

The earlier given solutions were the easiest I could think of (and I hoped they would satisfy your requirements). However, I now found that the exact solution to your question actually is more or less as easy.
This time, we just add the following `:filter-args` [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) on `dired-noselect`:

```lisp
(defun my-dired-org-filter-advice (args)
  (let ((dir (expand-file-name (file-name-as-directory (car args)))))
    (when (string= dir "/full-path-to-dir/") ; include final slash here
      (setf (car args) (concat dir "*.org")))
    args))

(advice-add 'dired-noselect :filter-args #'my-dired-org-filter-advice)
```

I'll keep the original answer below for the alternative solutions and for the 'modification' suggestions.

END EDIT

---

It is probably easiest to simply define a custom command for it. The exact form of the function then depends on your exact requirements. Here is a simplest example, in case you'd only use it for opening a single directory.

```lisp
(defun my-open-org-dir ()
  (interactive)
  (dired "/path-to-dir/*.org"))
```

Of course, the function can be made more general, where you could prompt for selecting a dir first.

After evaluating the above code, e.g. by adding it to your init file, and restart Emacs, you can call the function via `M-x` or bind the function to some key(-sequence).

If you prefer to 'modify' the original `dired` (C-x d) command, then you could add a [:filter-return advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-Combinators.html) on the function `dired-read-dir-and-switches` to conditionally add (`concat`) `*.org` after the filename for certain (matching) directories.
For example, you could use the following advice for it:

```lisp
(defun my-dired-org-filter-advice (output)
  (let ((dir (car output)))
    (when (string= dir "/full-path-to-directory/") ;; include the final slash
      (setf (car output) (concat dir "*.org")))
    (print output)))

(advice-add 'dired-read-dir-and-switches :filter-return #'my-dired-org-filter-advice)
```

where, of course, you should fill in the correct full directory path.
If you'd like to use it for multiple dirs, then replace `string=` by [member](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sets-And-Lists.html) and pass your list of directories.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't exactly understand how I can use this. I will be pasting the code to my `.emacs` then how do activate it?

Comment: OP: You invoke it using `M-x my-open-org-dir`. Or bind that command to a key and use the key to invoke it.

Comment: @dalanicolai: You might want to show an example of defining the advice.

Comment: I have added usage instructions and an example advice to the answer.

Comment: Ok, this is better, now I can do the same with `M-x my` (emacs suggested this shortcut) but I was hoping for a permanent set up. So, I have a directory `~NEW/` and anytime I open this directory, it would be nice to have it with only `.org` files showing without me entering each time `M-x my`. But I guess, this is OK, thanks.

Comment: (This is a comment on the latest, "better" solution, i.e. the `:filter-args` advice on `dired-noselect`). The main problem  I see is the hardwiring of the path. Could that be avoided by defining a directory local-variable for it? I don't see any reason why it wouldn't but I haven't tried it either.

Comment: @NickD I also want to try to save export files to another directory. I tried a couple of answers on this old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559753/emacs-org-mode-export-to-another-directory but couldn't make it work. Can you suggest a better way of exporting to a different directory?

Comment: @NickD What problem do you see in 'hardwiring' of the path (in a 'curstom/personal' solution)?

Comment: It only works for that path: I may have more than one directory where I would want the filter active.

Comment: @zeynel: exporting to a different directory does not seem related to this question at all. If so, you should ask that in a separate question. Tacking a new question in a comment to an existing question is bad practice that should be avoided.

Comment: @NickD Ah okay, I see. I have mentioned the option to use `member` with a list of directories instead of the `string=` in the original answer. That is what the `'modification suggestions' is referring to. I know that I could have made that more clear, but find that very important as I do expect from a questioner to 'fully' read/study/think about answers (at least the short ones). And also, that was not part of the question. Anyway, of course your feedback is appreciated, so let me know if you have 'a different opinion'...

Comment: I always prefer solutions where the code is generic and I can influence it from the outside, without having to modify it. But you are right: that's a different question.